# python - Find all indexes for the matching value in a list of ordered dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having a list of ordered dict which looks similarly as below

```
[OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)]), OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 3)]), OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', 2)]), OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 2)]), OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 3)])]
```

I wanted to store indexes of list in an array which are the `a` value as `1`
So, my list would contain below elements

> [0,1,4]

I'm having a traditional script to get these values but since my original list is holding more than a million ordered dicts, it's taking a longer time to fetch the elements.

```
for ele in range(len(liso)):
 if(liso[ele]['a'] ==1):
  giso.add(ele)
```

Can someone help me to rewrite the above script using `map` or `filter` to optimize the query?

Comment: First, what version of Python is this? Also, what exactly is `giso`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List Comprehension: `[i for i, x in enumerate(liso) if x['a'] == 1]`

Filter:

If you're using Python 2: `filter(lambda i: liso[i]['a'] == 1, xrange(len(liso)))`

If you're using Python 3: `list(filter(lambda i: liso[i]['a'] == 1, range(len(liso))))`

Comment: Why would you use `range(len())` here? Particularly if this is Python 2.

Comment: @roganjosh What else would you recommend?

Comment: Laptop died, on phone now so excuse formatting. In python 2, range will create the whole list rather than an iterator. In python 2, use `xrange` instead (OP didn't clarify from my question). For this example: `[item for item in liso if item['a'] == 1]`.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks, I never knew `xrange` iterates lazily through a range.

Comment: You're welcome. That issue is gone in Python 3, `range` from P2 is gone. `range(len())` is usually best replaced with `enumerate` in both versions.

Comment: Arg, I'm too slow to respond on phone. Ditch the indices entirely from your list comp. My second comment is the pythonic way. Try it.

Comment: @roganjosh OP wants the indices though

Comment: That's true. I'm giving up for the night since I can only see small parts at a time :) use `[i for i, x in enumerate(liso) if x['a'] == 1]`

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the suggestion, I'll edit the post!

Comment: @Copperfield My bad, I don't compile with Python 2 so I assumed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ducks would work well here. It builds a database-style index on Python objects.

`pip install ducks`

```
from ducks import Dex

objects = [OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)]), OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 3)]), OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', 2)]), OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 2)]), OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 3)])]

# build index on objects
dex = Dex(objects, ['a', 'b'])

# get matching objects
dex[{'a': 1}]  # gets objects where a == 1
dex[{'b': 2}]  # gets objects where b == 2
dex[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]  # gets objects where a == 1 and b == 2
dex[{'a': {'<': 3}}] # gets objects where a < 3
```

On a million-item dataset, those queries will run 10 to 100x faster than filter / list comprehensions, which must scan through every object every time.